# list.pop() function when having a list in list situation

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am having a problem understanding the following code:

Here's an example I have coded:

```
listA=[]
listB=[]
listA.append(10)
print(listA)
listB.append(listA)
print(listB)
listA.pop()
print(listA)
print(listB)
```

I was expecting the shell to print out the following result:

```
[10]
[[10]]
[]
[[10]]
```

But in reality what I got was:

```
[10]
[[10]]
[]
[[]]
```

I don't understand the logic behind this. If I alter the code into this:

```
listA=[]
listB=[]
listA.append(10)
print(listA)
listB.append(listA)
print(listB)
listA=[]
print(listA)
print(listB)
```

This would get what I expected. 
I would hope if anyone can tell me why the two codes give different results yet the action of the codes is the same?

Comment: Since you save a reference to listA in listB and modify listA, also listB changes if you print it!? With your expected results you have to copy or clone the list and not hold a reference.

Comment: so does that mean I cannot use stack function if I am trying to do what I did in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables (in python) are like handles. `listA` is just a handle to some other place where your list actually resides.
You assembled a structure looking like this, where the arrows mean "points to":

[image: initial structure]

Then, in your first case, you took the `10` out by calling `pop()`. But it was still the same box, hence it looked like this:

[image: pop]

However, in the second case all you did was reassign your `A` handle to a new list `[]`:

[image: reassignment]

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting confused is that `Python` `lists` are `mutable` as opposed to `immutable` data types like `strings`. This means that they are passed by **`reference`** - *not* by **`value`**.

So when you call:

```
listB.append(listA)
```

you are not adding the `contents` of `listA` as a `list` into `listB`, you are passing the `reference` to where `listA` is in *`memory`* to `listB`.

This means that when you remove the `10` from `listA` with a `pop()`, you are changing the location in `memory` for `listA`. Therefore, when you `print` `listB`, it looks up the `reference` for `listA`, find it has no contents (as you `popped` the `10`) and `prints` an empty `list`.

In the `second` `code`, you do something different (i.e. they are not the same as you said). Here, you do not `pop` the `10` from `listA` to make the `list` `empty`, you instead reassign the variable named `listA` to an `empty` `list` by doing:

```
listA = []
```

This produces a different result because the `reference` to the previous `listA` with the `[10]` is still held in `listB`. So when you modify the `variable` `listA`, you assign it a new chunk of `memory` where it will store its contents. Meanwhile the old chunk of memory with the `[10]` stays unmodified so `listB` stays unmodified as `[[10]]`.